# Is Geofencing API required ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission to make app working in foreground on Android 10(Q)?

Tags: android, geofencing, android-10.0

I'm testing my app on Android 10(Q) device. I'm using `FusedLocationProviderClient` to get location updates after specific interval. I'm getting location updates with "***Allow only while using the app***" permission. But Geofencing event won't trigger if I didn't allow "***Allow all the time***(ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION )" permission. I just wanted to trigger geofence event when app is open(in foreground) without ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission. I have used `BroadcastReceiver` and `PendingIntent` to detect geofence event as per https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing this official document.

Any help will be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Google's Geofencing API won't work without the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission. It doesn't matter if your app is in the foreground or using a foreground service, to use the `GeofencingClient` your app must have the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission.